# How can I get bar height on click in chartjs 2.6.0

Tags: javascript, charts, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a bar chart. When I click on one of the bar, I want it to return its height. I have tried adding a mouse clcik event to the chart but that didn't work. So how can I get the bar height when it is clicked?

Here is the code that I use to create the chart..

```
new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: cm_labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Number of votes',
      data: cm_data,
     backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
}}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add **`onClick`** method to your chart options, which will fire when the chart detects any click on itself.

Then to get the actual bar height when the **`onClick`** method is fired, you can use [**`getElementAtEvent()`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente) method, as such :

```
onClick: function(event) {
   var bar = this.getElementAtEvent(event);
   if (!bar.length) return; //return if not clicked on bar
   var barHeight = bar[0].height();
   alert(barHeight);
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      onClick: function(event) {
         var bar = this.getElementAtEvent(event);
         if (!bar.length) return; //return if not clicked on bar
         var barHeight = bar[0].height();
         alert(barHeight);
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot :)