# ChartJS 3 get height of stacked vertical bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Ok. So I'm trying to use ChartJS with Datalabels 2.0 (RC) to show labels for stacked vertical bars. When the bar is small, I want those labels to appear outside of it.

Now here is the code I'm using: https://codepen.io/meexo/pen/xxqpELL

The problem I have is that using `getProps` on dataset, I am unable to retrieve the height of each bar. In the example above I tried to get height by using the `getProps()` introduced in ChartJS 3. If I `console.log` it, I see all kind of params, height included (though undefined). What am I doing wrong that height parameter is undefined?

I also tried to use `getProps().y` param for the code, but in that case it seems to apply only to one section of the stacked bar, not all. And what I want is for labels to appear above the stacked bar when the full height if it is lower than my threshold.

Any ideas?

BTW, though its my first question, its definitely not the first answer I found on StackOverflow :)

My code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        }, {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'blue'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true
            },
            y: {
                stacked: true
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: context => {
                    let bar = context.chart.getDatasetMeta(context.datasetIndex).data[context.dataIndex].getProps().height;
                    document.getElementById('myHeight').innerHTML = bar;
                    const threshold = 6;

                    if (bar + threshold > context.chart.chartArea.bottom) {
                        return 'end'
                    }
                    return 'center'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok. So I am trying to go another path to just get the height of bar. Using onClick handler to get clicked bar height. Still undefined. See pen and try clicking on bars: https://codepen.io/meexo/pen/gOmoGJw

Comment: hi there maybe this could point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765886/how-can-i-get-bar-height-on-click-in-chartjs-2-6-0. The method getElementAtEvent does not seem to work but maybe you will find something that might help. I was tinkering with your codepen but I also don't seem to get the height of bar (I can get the width but not height)

Comment: @JacckMark I actually found that answer before and used as a starting point for my second Codepen (in the comments). But since I'm using ChartJS 3 (not 2.6), getElementAtEvent has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour comes from this part in the code:

```js
const properties = {
        horizontal,
        base: vpixels.base,
        enableBorderRadius: !stack || isFloatBar(parsed._custom) || (me.index === stack._top || me.index === stack._bottom),
        x: horizontal ? vpixels.head : ipixels.center,
        y: horizontal ? ipixels.center : vpixels.head,
        height: horizontal ? ipixels.size : undefined,
        width: horizontal ? undefined : ipixels.size
      };
```

It sets the `height` on `undefined` for normal bar charts and the `width` on `undefined` on horizontal bar charts. Putted in a pr (https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/9208) for fix so this should be fixed by the next release of `chart.js`

Then to get the bar height you have to change your mode to `index` and then you can use this function to get the total bar height:

```js
onClick: function(event) {
        var bar = this.getElementsAtEventForMode(event, 'index', {intersect: true}, true);
        if (!bar.length) return; //return if not clicked on bar
        var barHeight = bar.reduce((acc , val) => (acc + val.element.height), 0)
        document.getElementById('myHeight').innerHTML = barHeight;
      }
```

Example: https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/qBrpLjX

Comment: Oh, I was just about writing an answer about your commit. There was also a temporary fix provided: use `element.y - element.base` to get the height of bar. This does work for now.